# How import and using browserDetection in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I trying to migrate from Angular2 to Angular4, but in Angular4 i get error:

- component:

  import { browserDetection } from '@angular/platform-browser/testing/src/browser_util';

  if (browserDetection.isWebkit && browserDetection.supportsNativeIntlApi && !browserDetection.isChromeDesktop &&
      !browserDetection.isOldChrome) {
      return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array).buffer], {type: mimeString});
    }
- error in console:

  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser/testing/src/browser_util' in '/Users/ivan/blablabla/src/app/+client/client-profile/shared'

Error appears when i run 'npm start'.
in Angular2 no errors and all working& How to fix this?

Comment: Please show us the code of the page you're trying to migrate. When and where does this error occur?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Try to import angular packages in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

And in main.ts use the refered packages

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Its all imported except ApplicationRef.

Comment: Why you importing import { browserDetection } from '@angular/platform-browser/testing/src/browser_util';

Comment: Hmm... IDE automatically inserts this way. I try shorten way, but gaet another errors, for example: `Module build failed: Error: /Users/ivan/newessay/essay_client_front/src/app/+client/client-profile/shared/upload-avatar.dialog.ts (5,10): Module '"/Users/ivan/newessay/essay_client_front/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/testing"' has no exported member 'browserDetection'.)`